# Exclude specific nservicebus host handlers (classes) in version 3.x

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

I have an NServiceBus host that is subscribed to some event and has its own handler (#1). This host also has a reference to an assembly which contains another handler (#2) for the same event. I want to exclude handler #2 from NServiceBus configuration, but I can't remove referenced assembly.

**Important**:

1) I tried to set up scanning using this: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning

2) I use NServiceBus version 3.x

Comment: What is the assembly name and can you add the code that you tried?

Comment: I don't need to exclude entire assembly, I just need to exclude some handlers from its assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Remove the assembly

NServiceBus v3 scans for assemblies. If the assembly isn't needed at runtime then just remove it so it will not be scanned.

Just because it is referenced doesn't make it required to be deployed.

### Excluding the assembly (blacklisting)

Exclude the assembly as mentioned in the documentation:

```
var allAssemblies = AllAssemblies
    .Except("MyAssembly1.dll")
    .And("MyAssembly2.dll");
Configure.With(allAssemblies);
```

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning#exclude-a-list-approach

### Include assemblies or types (whitelisting)

Only allow a specific set of assemblies or types to be scanned. Basically parsing a whitelisted range of assemblies or types.

Assemblies:

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> allowedAssembliesToScanForTypes;
Configure.With(allowedAssembliesToScanForTypes);
// or
Configure.With(assembly1, assembly2);
```

Types:

```
IEnumerable<Type> allowedTypesToScan;
Configure.With(allowedTypesToScan);
```

### Exclude specific types

```
// Results in the same assembly scanning as used by NServiceBus internally
var allTypes = from a in AllAssemblies.Except("Dummy") 
               from t in a.GetTypes()
               select t;

// Exclude handlers that you do not want to be registered
var allowedTypesToScan = allTypes
    .Where(t => t != typeof(EventMessageHandler)) 
    .ToList();

Configure.With(allowedTypesToScan);
```

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning#include-a-list-approach-including-assemblies

Comment: Thank you, but could you please read important notes in my question

Comment: Denis, I've added an additional snippet Exclude specific types, please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but my code is in production already. But your answer is correct